# Submit list of objects from jsp to controller

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have dynamically varying list of parameters that I need to pass from a jsp page to spring mvc controller, how do I achieve this?  Please provide a suggestion or a pseudo code so that I can proceed with my development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax from the .jsp to your controller with POST or GET.

**.jsp:**

```
<%
    Gson gson = new Gson();
%>
<script>
var json = "<% out.println(gson.toJson(myList).toString()); %>";

function sendData() {
    "use strict";
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("data send to my controller ...");
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/url_of_my_controller?value=" + json, false); 
    xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
```

**controller.java:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url_of_my_controller", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String     controller(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (request.getParameter("value") != null) {
        Gson                    gson = new Gson();
        List<foo>               list = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("value"), List<foo>);

        System.out.println(request.getParameter("value"));
        return ("ok");
    }
    return ("ko");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="blammo">
  <input type="hidden" name="hoot"/> <!-- dynamically add hidden elements to -->
                                     <!-- myForm then submit it -->
</form>
```